# How to Quiet[] only the first argument of Check[]?

Tags: error-tracking, error-trapping

I have a Check of the form

```
Check[expr,failexpr, {NIntegrate::slwcon}]
```

If *expr* throws *slwcon*, I would like to redo the calculation with higher precision by instead evaluating *failexpr*. But if there is *still* a problem even with higher precision (while evaluating *failexpr*), I need the error message to show so that I am aware of this. On the other hand, if *expr* throws *slwcon*, it should not show that error, since it is already handled and if it shows, I won't know if it's an error I already handled or not without explicitly checking the stack trace for every error, and that sucks!

There seems to be no solution to this using just Quiet[]:

If I try Quiet[expr, {NIntegrate::slwcon}] the check never activates and it never evaluates *failexpr*.

But if I put Quiet around the whole Check, then if the *failexpr* still fails, I get no error message so I never know about it. That is bad.

It seems like Check[] should just have the option (if not by default!) to quiet only *expr*, but not *failexpr*. But it's just not there. Is there a simple solution?

Comment: does this give what you need: `Catch@Check[expr,Throw[failexpr], {NIntegrate::slwcon}]`?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it would. I still get an error if expr is handled by check, at least in a test case: Catch[Check[1/0, 23.1, {Power::infy}]] still shows the Power::infy error from the 1/0. I can't check my actual integral right now because it takes 6 hours of cpu time to get up to that computation.

Comment: how about: `quietRest = 
  Function[{exp, failexp, ms}, 
   Check[On[ms]; exp, Off[ms]; failexp, {ms}], HoldAll];
quietRest[1/0, {2/0, 3/4, 3/0}, Power::infy]`?

Comment: Still get quietRest[1/0, 23.1, Power::infy] giving Power::infy error, on mathematica 12.0.

Comment: @kglr Perhaps `Catch@Quiet[
  Check[expr, 
   Throw[Unevaluated@
     failexpr], {NIntegrate::slwcon}], {NIntegrate::slwcon}]`? The trick here is to keep `failexpr` from evaluating until it's outside `Quiet`.

Comment: Almost. expr=1 gives 1. expr=1/0 with failexpr=23.1 gives 23.1 with no error, as it should. But expr=1/0 with failexpr=23.1/0 gives ComplexInfinity with no error message, though an error should be printed here.

Answer (score 6):

Mmm, something like this?

```
ClearAll[try]
SetAttributes[try, HoldAllComplete]
try[expr_, failexpr_, messages : {___MessageName} | PatternSequence[]] := Module[
  {tag},
  ReleaseHold @ Catch[
    Quiet[
     Check[
      HoldComplete[#]& @ expr,
      Throw[HoldComplete[failexpr], tag],
      messages
     ],
     messages
    ],
    tag
   ]
 ]
```

Comment: This works. I don't know how, because the syntax is kind of beyond me haha, but it works. I guess I should understand why, though. So now I am looking up a whole lot of syntax.

Comment: Having a lot of trouble with message: {___MessageName} | PatternSequence[]. If you could give a brief general idea of what this should do it would be really helpful, even just a sentence or two

Comment: @doublefelix That defines an argument called `messages`, (see [`:`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html)), that can be one of two things (see [`|`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html)): Either, a list of zero or more (see [`___`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html)) [`MessageName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageName.html) expressions, or an empty sequence of arguments (see [`PatternSequence[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence.html)), meaning the argument can be left away

Comment: Now I am trying to understand, if I use this function multiple times, do I have to keep setting the attribute to HoldAllComplete after each use or does it suffice to do so once before the initial definition? Sorry I am new (2 weeks) to mathematica.

Comment: It is enough to evaluate these lines just once and then simply use `try[foo, bar, ...]`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to achieve the desired effect would be to write:

```
Quiet@Check[expr, $Failed, {NIntegrate::slwcon}] /. $Failed :> failexpr
```

If we are worried about a collision with the symbol `$Failed`, we can choose a different symbol or generate a new one, e.g.

```
Module[{failed}
, Quiet@Check[expr, failed, {NIntegrate::slwcon}] /. failed :> failexpr
]
```

Comment: This is most likely the best answer and I only didn't test or implement it yet because I was in a time crunch and already had the other option implemented. Just to make other readers of the answer aware..